# Regex for a shared path

Tags: c#, regex

I am having issues with a regex for server paths. I have many paths and they can differentiate like:

```
\\server1\folder\file
```

or

```
\\server2\folder\subfolder\file
```

I need to get the server name out of it and only the server name. I have tried using

```
[\\(.*?)\\]
```

which gets the inverse of what I want and multiple parts rather than just the server name. What is the proper expression?

Comment: \\(.*?)\\ Will capture the first phrase between two \.

Comment: `string host = new Uri(@"\\server2\folder\subfolder\file").Host;`

Comment: @AlexK. Thank you, thank is a much cleaner solution that can be implemented on a larger scale such as what I wish to accomplish.

Comment: Alex's Answer is the best, but just for completeness, I think the RegEx you want is `(?<=\\\\)[^\\]*`

Comment: You can use string split : string input = @"\\server2\folder\subfolder\file";
           string output = input.Split(new char[] {'\\'}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).FirstOrDefault();

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This regex matches everything between the `\\` and the first `\`:

```
(?<=\\\\)[^\\]*
```

**Explanation**

- `(?<=\\\\)`  - starts with double `\`
- `[^\\]*`     - matches any character except `\`